# Math and non-math text bookmark doesn't work

Tags: math-mode, bookmarks, text

I have the following mwe. I see the correct section heading in the .pdf file but in the generated bookmark the math part is missing. Any help in fixing this is much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\section{The value of \texorpdfstring{$x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}$}{} % 
is blah blah 
     }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something to appear in the PDF bookmark, you have to write it in the second argument of `\texorpdfstring` - for example

```
\texorpdfstring{$x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}$}{x\^{}n + y\^{}n = z\^{}n}
```

Note the second argument is just plain text, and the "trick" for getting a `^` character by putting the accent over "nothing" (i.e. the empty string `{}`).

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. If I may ask,  if I want to add another line to the title, like, "for $n \geq 1$", how can I achieve that ?